# Why is $\log z = \ln r + i\theta$ ($r>0, \alpha <\theta < \alpha + 2\pi$) discontinuous at $\alpha$?

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, continuity

In one book on complex variables it is written that, given the function $\log z = \ln r + i\theta$ (for proper citation, let's call it function (2), as in the book) ($r>0, \alpha <\theta < \alpha + 2\pi$), where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and $z\in\mathbb{C}$, it is discontinuous at $\theta = \alpha$ because:

> Note that if the function (2) were to be defined on the ray $\theta = \alpha$, it would not be continuous there. For if $z$ is a point on that ray, there are points arbitrarily close to $z$ at which the values of $v$ are near $\alpha$ and also points such that the values of $v$ are near $\alpha+2\pi$.

*[We also note to the above excerpt that $u(r,\theta) = \ln r$ and $v(r,\theta)=\theta$.]*

Unfortunately, I don't understand what the quote above means, i.e. why this function would be discontinuous at $\theta = \alpha$. Would someone please clarify this for me?

Comment: I mean, try approaching from one side and the other, one gives $\ln r +i\alpha$ the other gives $\ln r + i(\alpha+2\pi)$. The definition of continuity is that limits are the same no matter how you approach.

Comment: The reason that the logarithm is discontinuous is that $\theta$ is multivalued.  For the same point $z$ in the complex plane, we can represent that point in polar coordinates by $(\rho, \theta+2\ell \pi)$ for all integer $\ell$.

Comment: @Dr.MV, why can't we define the branch as $\alpha < \theta \le \alpha + 2\pi$? Then there wouldn't be a branch cut.

Comment: @sequence Then the branch cut would be along $\theta =\alpha$.

Comment: @Dr.MV But $\theta = \alpha$ is already "covered" by $\theta = \alpha + 2\pi$.